# Randomizing an integer of 2D array address

Tags: java, arrays, random, 2d

I am trying to randomize integers for the parameters of a 2D array.

array[i][j]: i can only be (0-2) and j can only be (0-2) as well.

The trick is to never duplicate an address so array[0][1] can only happen once for example.

Any hints as to how to implement this? Could I do this using random()?

Comment: need more detail, unable understand what you want to do.

Comment: I have 2 sets of numbers that are identical. For example {123} and {123}. I want to get all possible pairs in a random order without repeating pairs. so 11, 12, 13, 21,22,23,31,32,33. Notice that no group of 2 integers are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle the Array in java.

here is a code for shuffling one dimensional array.

```
ArrayList<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<=array.length;i++)
{
    this.cards.add(array[i]);
}
Collections.shuffle(this.arraylist);
```